# Using datepicker values as autofilter arguments in excel2010 vba

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker, autofilter

As the title says I'm trying to use a the value from a DTpicker object to filter a range of dates trying to find dates later than the input value.

The dates are input in format dd/mm/yyyy which I believe should be ok.

The code I'm struggling with is basically the following line, as i run it it simply does not find any values.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rådata").AutoFilterMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rådata").Range("N1:N700").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=>" & DTPickerFra.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel format for your criteria is 'greater then or equal to' instead of the other way around.

I got it to work by changing Criteria1 to ">=" instead of "=>"

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rådata").AutoFilterMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rådata").Range("N1:N700").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & DTPickerFra.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: Ahhhh! Helped :)
Follow up, it seems that the dd/mm gets switched around?
Dates are input dd/mm/yyyy, which is also the format DTpicker seems to use, but somehow if I put in 8/11-13 in datepicker, I get all dates later than 11th of August not the 8th of Oct...

Comment: Glad it worked. I assumed your date input was consistent with the dates in col N.  You'll probably have to convert the datepicker format to meet your data format.

Comment: Yes, had to pull out day and month values seperately, switched them in a new string.